# Mule Development structure

Tags: mule

I am trying to develop one mule application using eclipse plugin . Mule version is 3.1 . Which  will be the base directory of my mule project (is  it Mule_Home/apps folder) ?

Or I need to develop it outside of Mule bundle and place corresponding jar file under Mule_Home/lib/user directory ? If so then again need to place mule-config file under apps folder ?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Here's the MuleStudio generated structure:

```
/lib
/mappings
/mule-project.xml
/src/main/api
/src/main/app
/src/main/java
/src/main/resources
/src/test
/src/test/resources
```

Your flows go in /src/main/app. Here's a sample pom file to build based on the structure above https://gist.github.com/tjsnell/8147194

Answer (score 2):

You can refer below link for the format.
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/application-format

> ### Mule Application Format
>
> The deployment unit of a Mule application encapsulates everything an >application needs to function, such as libraries, custom code, configuration, >deployment descriptor and any environment properties accompanying the >application. It exists in one of two formats:
>
> - .zip file (a regular archive with a 'zip' extension)
> - unpacked version of the same .zip file (exploded app)
>
>   ```
>   \- classes                 // application-specific expanded resources (e.g. logging configuration files, properties, etc
>   |- lib                     // application-specific jars
>   |- plugins                 // application plugins files
>   \- lib                  // application shared plugin jars (FROM 3.7 and +)
>   |- mule-config.xml         // Main Mule configuration file, also monitored for changes
>   |- mule-deploy.properties  // Application deployment descriptor (optional)
>   |- mule-app.properties     // custom properties to be added to the registry instance used by the application (optional)
>   |- *.grf files             // produced by DataMapper to plot its data mapping
>   ```
>
> Mule supports the deployment of both packaged (zipped) and exploded (unzipped) applications.
>
> You can share libraries between applications via the application deployment descriptor attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to know [Mule Application Format](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Application+Format)

Answer (score 0):

Tracy Snell is right. I use Anypoint Studio and the Mule source folder on the build path is src/main/app. That's where your mule-app.properties, mule.deploy.properties, and your project_name.xml go.

Answer (score 0):

Mule-project.xml is the main xml to define your flow and you can add more xml's flows to your main xml if required and mule-app.properties and mule-deploy.properties will be loaded in the flow by default to acess the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You have to develop your new application in /src/main/app folder.
if you want to include any resources like static
properties that have to be developed in /src/main/resources folder.
if you want to include any java resources that has to be in /src/main/java.

Comment: Add more explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue